# Display image via url from firebase database using html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

ow can I display images via url and it increments?

My table increments every time new data is stored. But how can I display image to my table?

The table already display the url I'm trying to display the image via url.
this is the output of my table https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sad-police-app.appspot.com/o/October 21 16:9:15?alt=media&token=14866e4f-7a7b-4f11-a057-106313770861

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Firebase Realtime Database Web</title>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.1/firebase.js"> 
  </script>
  <script>
     // Initialize Firebase

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

   <div class="tablehead">
   <h1>POLICE STATION 3</h1>
   <table id="reports" border="1">
    <tr>
     <th>Case ID</th>
     <th>Email Address</th>
     <th>Caption</th>
     <th>Location</th>
     <th>Time</th> 
     <th>Picture</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="reportbody"></tbody>
   </table>
  </div>

  <script>
    var tblUsers = document.getElementById('reportbody');
    var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('PP3/');
    var rowIndex = 1;

    databaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      tblUsers.innerHTML = '';
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
       var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
       var childData = childSnapshot.val();

     var row = tblUsers.insertRow(0);
      var ccase= row.insertCell(0);
     var email = row.insertCell(1);
     var caption = row.insertCell(2);
     var location = row.insertCell(3);
     var time = row.insertCell(4);
     var picture = row.insertCell(5);
     ccase.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.CaseID.replace(/"/g, '')));
     email.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Email.replace(/"/g, '' )));
     caption.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Caption.replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/"/g, '')));
     location.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Location.replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/"/g, '')));
     time.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Time.replace(/"/g, '')));
     picture.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Picture.replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/"/g, '')));
     rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
  });
    });
  </script>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `` SomeNode.appendChild(`<img src=${url}>`) ``

Comment: hello where will I insert it?

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21187909)

Comment: Hello I've inserted the image for my question maybe it can help :)